# Depriving your application to run multiple times

Tags: java

I created an application in java and I want it to run only once. If the application is already running, a messagebox should popup telling the user that the application is already running.

Any idea?

Comment: run the application as an instance from another class and keep the checking there

Comment: Use a lock file; use a socket

Answer (score 0):

You can check the running programs pid names for an instance of the current program.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed example on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Or

Run the application as an instance from another class and keep the check in the other class.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed example on how to do it?

Comment: so now you moved the problem from one class to another!?